# DAX Duplicate Count in measure with Previous Date

Tags: duplicates, dax, measure

I Need a DAX measure where date wise only duplicate values will return. The date will search always previous + Current Date. Ex: on date 2/2/2022, it will check both 2/1/2022 and 2/2/2022 and return only duplicate count.

Below Data set Count of on 2/2/2022 Duplicate will return 4. which is highlighted in

[image]

Total Output will be:

[image]

I already write a DAX but it just return unique count not only duplicate:

```
CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(data[Wrap-up]),DATESINPERIOD(data[Date],MAX(data[Date]),-2,DAY))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MyMeasure :=
VAR ThisDate =
    MAX( data[Date] )
VAR MyTable =
    SUMMARIZE(
        FILTER( ALL( data ), data[Date] <= ThisDate && data[Date] >= ThisDate - 1 ),
        data[Wrap-up],
        "MyCount", COUNTROWS( data )
    )
RETURN
    SUMX( MyTable, IF( [MyCount] > 1, [MyCount] ) )
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. Its solved my purpose.

Comment: Hi @Jos Woolley, "Grand Total Row" only showing last day value. Is there any way in Grand Total SUM of all count will be displayed

Comment: @HijbulBari Can you paste your first table as copiable text, rather than a picture, so that I can use it for testing purposes without having to reproduce it myself?

Answer (score 0):

```html
Date    Wrap-up
2/1/2022    Subscription_ACCBalance_QFTR
2/1/2022    Package_AKASH Lite Plus_RFTR
2/1/2022    Package_AKASH LITE_RFTR
2/1/2022    Subscription_Service Act_QFTR
2/1/2022    Package_AKASH Lite Plus_RFTR
2/1/2022    Camp Offer_Referral Offer_RFTR
2/2/2022    Content_Specefic Channel_CFTR
2/2/2022    Subscription_ACCBalance_QFTR
2/2/2022    Package_AKASH STANDARD_RFTR
2/2/2022    Camp Offer_Referral Offer_QFTR
2/2/2022    Error Code_E17-0_CFTR
2/3/2022    Package_AKASH STANDARD_RFTR
2/3/2022    Package_AKASH STANDARD_QFTR
2/3/2022    Package_Package Info_QFTR
2/3/2022    Package_AKASH LITE_QFTR
2/4/2022    Subscription_ACCBalance_QFTR
2/4/2022    Content_Specefic Channel_QFTR
2/4/2022    Info Update_HelpPage_CFTR
2/4/2022    Purchase_General Process_QFTR
2/4/2022    Package_AKASH STANDARD_RFTR
2/4/2022    Recharge_bKash_QFTR
2/4/2022    Camp Offer_Feb Recharge_QFTR
2/4/2022    Subscription_Classific_QFTR
```

Date        Wrap-up
2/1/2022    Subscription_ACCBalance_QFTR
2/1/2022    Package_AKASH Lite Plus_RFTR
2/1/2022    Package_AKASH LITE_RFTR
2/1/2022    Subscription_Service Act_QFTR
2/1/2022    Package_AKASH Lite Plus_RFTR
2/1/2022    Camp Offer_Referral Offer_RFTR
2/2/2022    Content_Specefic Channel_CFTR
2/2/2022    Subscription_ACCBalance_QFTR
2/2/2022    Package_AKASH STANDARD_RFTR
2/2/2022    Camp Offer_Referral Offer_QFTR
2/2/2022    Error Code_E17-0_CFTR
2/3/2022    Package_AKASH STANDARD_RFTR
2/3/2022    Package_AKASH STANDARD_QFTR
2/3/2022    Package_Package Info_QFTR
2/3/2022    Package_AKASH LITE_QFTR
2/4/2022    Subscription_ACCBalance_QFTR
2/4/2022    Content_Specefic Channel_QFTR
2/4/2022    Info Update_HelpPage_CFTR
2/4/2022    Purchase_General Process_QFTR
2/4/2022    Package_AKASH STANDARD_RFTR
2/4/2022    Recharge_bKash_QFTR
2/4/2022    Camp Offer_Feb Recharge_QFTR
2/4/2022    Subscription_Classific_QFTR

Comment: Hi @Jos Woolley, You can Copy the text and paste in Notepad to see the dataset tabular way.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).